asp-page generates null url when optional route paramotor not set, but non route paramotor exists
The asp-page and Url.Page functions return a null, however this is unexpected.
The way I would think it would work is the razor page "Test" has the directive
@page "{Opt1:int?}"

The index page links to the test page,  but I would expect the valid url "https://localhost:7230/Test?Other=3" to be generated when Opt1 is null
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    int? Opt1a = null;
    int? Opt1b = 2;
}
 
<a asp-page="/Test" asp-route-Other="3" asp-route-Opt1="@Opt1a">Test</a> @* https://localhost:7230/Test?Other=3 but not work *@
<a asp-page="/Test" asp-route-Other="3" asp-route-Opt1="@Opt1b">Test</a> @* https://localhost:7230/Test/2?Other=3 *@

I guessing this is just the way it works but it feels likes a bug, any suggestions on how to handle this?
Thanks

I don't know why, if I am using @page "{Opt1?}", it will works fine. Will check it  later.
